# Распаковка словарей

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему `*kwargs` получаем ключи, а `**kwargs` не получаем кортежи `(key, val)`и функция понимает- это как аргументы ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дополню всё же, что ну просто так задумано.

`*` - итерирует объект, к которому она применяется, и отдаёт результат, при этом итерирование словаря, как известно, даёт в результате именно его ключи

`**` - даёт пары `ключ=значение`, и это удобно во многих случаях, в частности для передачи аргументов в функцию через словарь

Answer (score 2):

`*` и `**` это разные операторы и поэтому работают по-разному. Так задумали авторы языка.

Кортежи (ключ, значение) можно получить `dct.items()` и распаковать их одной звёздочкой если нужно.